# Having problem with Next.js while adding additional script

Tags: next.js

Image

[image: 1]

I'm working with next js for a digital agency website. There are several scripts that we should use in our next app. Firstly we tried to use script in _document.js file. Then we tried to create a component with those scripts and import it where it is needed. But unfortunately we failed in both cases. The scripts doesn't work. We also tried to use Script component from next. It’s also not working. But while we use those scripts directly to the component, as shown in the image, surprisingly it works. But we don’t want to use them every time with every components directly. We want to use it for one time but should work for every components that rendered. Is there any way to do this? I'm a new bee in this programing world. So I'm expecting help from my elders. Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to write those scripts for one time and expecting from them to do work for all the pages that rendered in the UI.